# Make MySQL actually return the fields

Tags: mysql, node.js

I made the following code:

```
if (scIDExists) {
        var x = con.query('SELECT posX, posY, posZ FROM players WHERE scID = '+socialID+'', function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('The following error happened while selecting scID from [players]: ' + err);
                throw err;
            }
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
```

The console.log(result) returns me this:

```
[ RowDataPacket { posX: 100, posY: 100, posZ: 100 } ]
```

I want it do return this:

```
100 100 100
```

Or atleast something I can work with.
How to? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following log:

```
[ RowDataPacket { posX: 100, posY: 100, posZ: 100 } ]
```

means that you have an array of a single element. This element is an instance of `RowDataPacket` class. You can access the properties like a normal object so you can access the value using:

```
console.log(result[0].posX) // returns 100
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll accept your asnswer once it allows me.

Comment: Also. What does the [0] stand for?

Comment: First element of the array